# One To One Polymorphic Eloquent CRUD Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have users table and 2 other tables with one to one polymorphic relationship a user can have any one type of profile.

when Users registered first time there is a radio button which select user type insert record into users table how do I add the morphs field into the database according to radio btn
follow this doc [Laravel 9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations)

**User model**

```
public function userable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Employee Model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'userable');
}
```

**Freelancer model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'userable');
}
```

**How to perform CRUD on userable by user type there will be dropdown for user type**

```
public function addUser()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = 'John Doe';
    $user->email = 'test@gmail.com';
    $user->password = bcrypt('12345678');

    $user->type = 'freelancer' or 'employee';
    $user->userable()->associate(feelancer());

    $user->save();
    return $user;
}
```

[image: User Table]

Employees Table
[image: Employees Table]

Freelancers Table
[image: Freelancers Table]